# Using Noether's theorem how does one determine the corresponding conserved quantity given a symmetry

Tags: science-based, physics, temperature, quantum

According to Noether's theorem, various symmetries in natural laws result in conservation laws. What conservation law would arise if temperature were translation symmetric? Note that I really don't care that temperature being symmetric doesn't make sense. Temperature here is just some asymmetric value that I would like to do a thought experiment with.

To clarify I'm asking what a universe would be like if there were a property such that for any temperature $T$, the transformation $T\rightarrow T+\delta T$ would not create a meaningful difference in the behavior of a system. What new conservation laws would emerge from this?

Edit: I think generalizing this problem might make it clearer. From my understanding of Noether's theorem, symmetries and conservation laws occur in corresponding pairs. Temperature is just an example here, my goal is to learn how to figure out the conservation law from the symmetry.

Comment: I'm not clear if the big-bang could even happen under such circumstances. Is this a whole universe you're referring to or a localised phenomenon in this one?

Comment: Seems like it would mean that entropy could be reversible under some conditions, and therefore perpetual-motion machines could also work under some conditions. Oops, the sun just crisped the Earth, too bad for us.

Comment: There is no guarantee a conservation law would arise even if temperature-translation symmetry existed. What might happen is that the laws of thermodynamics would be different. If that happened, some odd and interesting things would be the case.

Comment: @user535733 That may be more possible than we would normally think. I came upon a remark that entropy should be covered by a conservation rule, but somehow this doesn't happen. So in the OP's scenario reversible entropy might be a thing. This might not guarantee perpetual motion machines. Biology might be quite remarkable, in fact, very, very remarkable.

Comment: @user535733 I did note your "under some conditions" and was making, what was basically the same point, in different words. I suspect there would be really weird stuff if entropy was reversible. Working out what was weird wouldn't be easy. Time & lots of thinking required. Don't have enough of either. The Sun might freeze Earth instead of crisping it.

Comment: This is rather broad. What happen to what? We can't cover the entire universe in one answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "temperature were translation symmetric"? What is unchanged under what change? What is getting translated?

Comment: Open ended" what would happen" questions are way to broad.

Comment: I am not at all certain that I understand what a temperature-translation symmetry is supposed to be. Does the word "translation" have the usual meaning of a transformation of the coordinates as $x = x + \Delta x, y = y + \Delta y, z = z + \Delta z$? How does this symmetry look like mathematically?

Comment: To help you understand the confusion people are having, when I read "temperature is translation symmetric," I say it already is.  If I have a Temperature field across the universe, and I translate the universe by some amount, it is the same thing as-if I had translated the temperatures within that universe by that amount."

Comment: FYI, the clarification doesn't make things any clear, at least for me.

Comment: I *still* don't get it. The laws of physics are *already* the same at any temperature. (Yes, there is a little handwaving here.) And an universe in which there is no absolute zero temperature is incompatible with what we usually understand by temperature. (Temperature is a measure of the average kinetic energey of the molecules in the system. If they are all at rest with respect with each other, how would the temperature be non-zero?)

Comment: The editing brings more sense into the question. Except that it makes it no longer a subject of WB, but better raised in Physics SE.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi should I repost the question into Physics SE, or try to get it migrated?

Comment: `should I repost the question into Physics SE, or try to get it migrated` Beat me if I know the difference or how the migration can be achieved. Never tried.

Comment: @tox123, the question is too old to be migrated. Please post it on your own in Physics.SE. Meanwhile I will keep it closed here.

Answer (score 6):

Temperature is not a coordinate like position, velocity, time, or rotation.  Symmetries on those coordinates lead to conservation of momentum, special relativity, conservation of energy, and conservation of angular momentum.  Symmetries of those values are aspects of the entire system, while temperature is an aspect of each part of the system.

Absolute zero is a real thing, a specific temperature below which things cannot go.  Its existence is dictated by the math of statistical dynamics.  You can't just move all the temperatures up or down.

Also, addressing some of the comments about "entropy being reversible":  At its most fundamental level, the laws of entropy translate to "things that are more likely to happen tend to happen more often."  If you calculate the entropies of different states, that's the math behind the calculations.

So saying "entropy tends to increase" is essentially a tautology.  It really can't go backward.

Answer (score 3):

I think that temperature is translationally symmetric already -- short of absolute zero.

You can add and scale temperature any way you want in a system, and then reduce the temperature back to the original value.  Now, the physical matter in that system may not return to its original state since it may undergo structural, physical, and chemical changes that are not reversible with temperature.

For example, if your system is a volume of H2 and O2 at standard temperature and pressure, and you raise the temperature high enough, you'll end up with H20 + OH + H2O2 vapor.  When you cool it down, it won't change back to diatomic gases.

But, if your system was a mass of Fe and you heated it up high enough, it would melt, then vaporize.  When you cooled it back down, you'd end up with an equal mass of Fe as you started, but it wouldn't likely have the same shape it as originally had.